# Why is the async [hidden] property not updating in this template?

Tags: angular

In a todo app, each plan `item` has an observable property on it called `task`. The task then has a property called `.done`. The item is hidden when `.done=false`.

However, in the following template, `[hidden]` is not *initially* taking the value assigned to it of `(itemComponent.task | async)?.done`:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of allItems$ | async">
  <app-item [item]="item" #itemComponent [hidden]="(itemComponent.task | async)?.done">
  </app-item>
</div>
```

#### The value of `task.done` doesn't initially propagate into `[hidden]`

I want the task to be hidden when the item is done however the hidden status isn't updating. ***At least it's not doing it initially***. It does do it when something triggers an Angular (11) update cycle.

#### `task.done` is definitely set

The obvious question is whether the item is correctly emitting a `task`. So I added the following line immediately under the `app-item` and inside the `*ngFor` loop:

```
<!-- test to see if task object is being emitted --> 
<span>{{(itemComponent.task | async)?.done}}</span>
```

This correctly prints the value of `item.task.done` from the first moment the page is loaded. But even though the value of `done` is as expected, it's not causing `[hidden]` to hide the elemnet. Why might that be?

Comment: Have you tested with `*ngIf` instead of `hidden`? Sometimes the `display` style attribute is set on the element and overrides the `hidden` property.

Comment: ngIf threw reference errors when I tried it - I think that because ngIf controls whether the element is even created in the first place it can't reference variables exposed from the element because, if I'm undersatnding correctly, they don't exist yet

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the asyncronous arrival of the `task` is causing the angular lifecycle to become unbalanced - it's arriving after a key lifecycle hook (e.g. `ngAfterContentChecked`). And for some reason the emission of the `task` does not cause angular to reevaluate the view.

To avoid this I exposed the `task` via an emitter rather than as a property. I also moved the `hidden` directive onto a container so that I could get a reference using a template variable:

```
<div #itemContainer *ngFor="let item of allItems$ | async">
  <app-item [item]="item"
            (onTask)="itemContainer.hidden = $event.done"></app-item>
  <!-- NB the $event object is a Task emitted from the app-item via Output() -->
</div>
```

This did the job just fine.